# heroku deployment issue - error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: heroku, create-react-app, service-worker

this was perfectly fine until i added a server to my cleint that was running with buildpacks mars/...
I made sure to remove all buildpacks with buildpacks:remove mars/...
I also tried heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
I also tried the git push heroku main:main

I am not sure but i think it maybe something with permissions but i may be wrong since i am new to heroku.

```
git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 74, done.
Counting objects: 100% (74/74), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (53/53), done.
Writing objects: 100% (68/68), 290.70 KiB | 58.14 MiB/s, done.
Total 68 (delta 15), reused 62 (delta 13), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote: NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote: NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote: NODE_ENV=production
remote: NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote: engines.node (package.json): 12.16.2
remote: engines.npm (package.json): 6.14.6
remote:
remote: Resolving node version 12.16.2...
remote: Downloading and installing node 12.16.2...
remote: Bootstrapping npm 6.14.6 (replacing 6.14.4)...
remote: npm 6.14.6 installed
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote: Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
remote: Module installation may take longer for this build
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote: Installing node modules
remote:
remote: > fsevents@1.2.13 install /tmp/build_ff6289e7/node_modules/fsevents
remote: > node install.js
remote:
remote:
remote: Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
remote:
remote: > nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/node_modules/nodemon
remote: > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
remote:
remote: Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
remote: > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
remote:
remote: added 375 packages in 6.258s
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote: Detected both "build" and "heroku-postbuild" scripts
remote: Running heroku-postbuild
remote:
remote: > everestminds-task@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_ff6289e7
remote: > cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build
remote:
remote:
remote: > node-sass@6.0.1 install /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/node-sass
remote: > node scripts/install.js
remote:
remote: Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v6.0.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node
remote: Download complete
remote: Binary saved to /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
remote: Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.vnweW/node-sass/6.0.1/linux-x64-72_binding.node
remote:
remote: > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:
remote:
remote: > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:
remote:
remote: > core-js@3.14.0 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:
remote:
remote: > core-js-pure@3.14.0 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
remote: > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:
remote:
remote: > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/ejs
remote: > node ./postinstall.js
remote:
remote:
remote: > protobufjs@6.11.2 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/protobufjs
remote: > node scripts/postinstall
remote:
remote:
remote: > node-sass@6.0.1 postinstall /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/node-sass
remote: > node scripts/build.js
remote:
remote: Binary found at /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
remote: Testing binary
remote: Binary is fine
remote: added 2146 packages from 876 contributors and audited 2150 packages in 55.156s
remote:
remote: 151 packages are looking for funding
remote: run npm fund for details
remote:
remote: found 7 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 4 high)
remote: run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details
remote: audited 2150 packages in 14.59s
remote:
remote: 151 packages are looking for funding
remote: run npm fund for details
remote:
remote: found 7 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 4 high)
remote: run npm audit fix to fix them, or npm audit for details
remote:
remote: > everestminds-task@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_ff6289e7/client
remote: > react-scripts build
remote:
remote: Creating an optimized production build...
remote: Failed to compile.
remote:
remote: Can't find self.__WB_MANIFEST in your SW source.
remote:
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! everestminds-task@0.1.0 build: react-scripts build
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the everestminds-task@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.vnweW/_logs/2021-06-27T21_07_28_897Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! everestminds-task@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the everestminds-task@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.vnweW/_logs/2021-06-27T21_07_28_915Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote: We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote: If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote: Love,
remote: Heroku
remote:
remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote: ! Push failed
remote: !
remote: ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 2c4fee55f03ca310626cd12afa9d269f1d95cc34
remote: !
remote: ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 2c4fee55f03ca310626cd12afa9d269f1d95cc34
remote: ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote: !
remote: ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote: !
remote: ! git push heroku :main
remote: !
remote: ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote: ! https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: ! Push rejected to everestminds-task.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/everestminds-task.git
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/everestminds-task.git'
```

server package.json

```
{
  "name": "everestminds-task",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.2",
    "npm": "6.14.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "stripe": "6.28.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

Client package.json

```
{
  "name": "everestminds-task",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "express-sslify": "^1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Alright, for anyone who comes across this. I found the problem, it was the serviceworker.js... it seems that "Can't find self.__WB_MANIFEST in your SW source"  has something to do with it.

create-react-app no longer comes with service-worker.js. So it maybe that I need to install a package that "swSrc" or something I am not sure yet.